# Bootstrap wrap broken in explorer v.11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to achieve a grid system containing 4 columns but explorer won't let me render it correctly. (I need it to work in compatibility view)

The code works fine in Chrome and the snippet below. Any tips for doing this in IE?

[image]

```css
.centercontainer {
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.maincol {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="widt=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container centercontainer" style="width: 960px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">hej</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11.576

Comment: Actually The above code works fine for me

Comment: Not for me unfortunately. It renders as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

So whatever I do, I cannot solve this without disabling compatibility view. This fixes the grid 100%.